# pandas: calculate percentiles within subgroups?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
 school_id  uni_id  points
 123        44      180
 123        45      160
 123        45      160
 123        48      110
 124        44      180
 124        45      160
 124        47      130
 123        48      120
```

Generated as follows, to help kind answerers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'school_id': [123, 123, 123, 123, 124, 124, 124, 124], 
    'school_id': [44, 45, 45, 48, 44, 45, 47, 48], 
    'points': [180, 160, 160, 110, 180, 160, 130, 120]
})
```

I'd like to add a percentile column, which represents the percentile of the `points` value for each school. So this dataset would look like this:

```
 school_id  uni_id  points  percentile
 123        44      180     100
 123        45      160     50
 123        45      160     50
 123        48      110     0
 124        44      180     100
 124        45      160     66
 124        47      130     33
 123        48      120     0
```

What's the best way to do this? I assume that I need to group by `school_id`, then do `df.quantile()` within each subgroup somehow, then ungroup?

**UPDATE**: Maybe I need to start with something like this... `df.groupby('school_id')['points'].rank(ascending=False)` and then divide the rank by the length of each group to normalise it between 0 and 100?

Comment: Take a look at @piRSquared's answer who seems to have read your mind correctly and come up with a solution matching the desired o/p of yours. If that is truly what you've wanted to do, you should accept his answer then and also probably upvote. But next time be very specific (including a rough calculation) as what you were asking here could be interpreted in many ways.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify `pct=True` while computing numerical data ranks between the subgroups grouped by `"school_id"` as an additional arg to [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html) method:

```
df.assign(percentile=df.groupby("school_id")['points'].rank(pct=True).mul(100))
```

[image]

***To check*** (for one instance):

```
from scipy.stats import percentileofscore
df.groupby("school_id")['points'].apply(percentileofscore, 160)

school_id
123    70.000000
124    66.666667
Name: points, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking to do several things here.

- you want your rankings to be dense
- you want to have the lowest be zero and the highest be 100.  I call this inclusive ranking

I create a separate function to apply with.

```
def dense_inclusive_pct(x):
    # I subtract one to handle the inclusive bit
    r = x.rank(method='dense') - 1
    return r / r.max() * 100

df.assign(pct=df.groupby('school_id').points.apply(dense_inclusive_pct).astype(int))

   points  school_id  uni_id  pct
0     180        123      44  100
1     160        123      45   50
2     160        123      45   50
3     110        123      48    0
4     180        124      44  100
5     160        124      45   66
6     130        124      47   33
7     120        124      48    0
```